# What's an LPSTREAM object and how can I use it?

Tags: c++, stream

I'm trying to write a function which will download the HTML source of a website and return it in a string, list, array, or really any usable format. To do this, I'm using a handy-looking function called [URLOpenBlockingStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127(v=vs.85).aspx), which will download a website's HTML source and place it in an object of type LPSTREAM.

```
//Saves the HTML souce of stackoverflow.com in the object "lps", of type LPSTREAM.
HRESULT hr = URLOpenBlockingStream(0, "http://www.stackoverflow.com/", &lps, 0, 0);
```

Now, what is this? I can find very few references to LPSTREAM anywhere on the internet, and none explaining how I get my data out of there. It may just be like an IStream object, but even that doesn't help, because using the insertion operator into a char array produces an error.

Answer (score 6):

It is a pointer to an [`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  "LP" stands for "Long Pointer," which just means "pointer" nowadays.  This is a common naming convention in the Windows SDK, for example see `LPVOID` (`void*`) and `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`).

You can always find out what a type is by finding where it is declared in the SDK (i.e., in the headers that you've included).  Or, in this case, the documentation for the [`URLOpenBlockingStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127.aspx) function you are calling says the following about the `ppStream` parameter:

> A pointer to the [`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034.aspx) interface on the stream object created by this function. The caller can read from the stream as soon as it has this pointer.

Comment: Ah, facepalm. Thanks for the fast reply!